# How can I create a database query inside the handle() method of a queue job class in Laravel 8.x

Tags: php, database, laravel, webhooks, jobs

I have a job class that recieves webhooks requests from a remote serve with a payload, i have access to this payload and i want to store it in database but the query i created is not working.

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use PHPUnit\Exception;
use Shakurov\Coinbase\Models\CoinbaseWebhookCall;

class HandleCreatedCharge implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    //** @var \Shakurov\Coinbase\Models\CoinbaseWebhookCall */
    public $webhookCall;

    public function __construct(CoinbaseWebhookCall $webhookCall)
    {
        $this->webhookCall = $webhookCall;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        // do your work here

        // you can access the payload of the webhook call with `$this->webhookCall->payload`
        $charge = $this->webhookCall->payload;
        $ref = $charge['event']['data']['metadata']['ref'];
        try {
             DB::table('cointrades')->where('ref', '=', $ref)->update(['status'=>'waiting']);
        }
        catch (Exception $exception){
           return $exception->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

please help a brother i am new to laravel queue jobs and webhooks handling.

Comment: whats the issue, You have almost defined it

Comment: yes i want to store the payload in database whenever a webhook request is sent to this job. but i've been listening to the request but no change in database

Comment: Have you confirmed that you had received the webhook? If so, You may change `$ref = $charge['event']['data']['metadata']['ref'];` to `$ref = Arr::get($charge, 'event.data.metadata.ref', null);` to have a try as there may be a chance that there is no that key (`['event']['data']['metadata']['ref']`) from the webhook...

Comment: thank you, it now works without the try-catch block.